# PHP Create variable using string as a name

Tags: php

I'm stuck for 2 hours now trying to create variables dynamically using names from an array. What am I missing?

```
private $filter_keys = array(
  'filter_warranty_id',
  'filter_service_centre_id'
}

foreach($this->filter_keys as $filter) {
  $($filter) => 'bla'
}
```

I've looked into variable variables, extract, compact, but none of these seem to get the job done.

Comment: there's an entire section on this [on the php website](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). The title is quite self-explanatory _"variable variables"_. But just a bit of friendly advise: ***don't do that***: variable variables, list and other such functions are just going to cause you grief in the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the code -

- Unexpected `}`
- missing `;`
- Syntax error `$($filter) => 'bla'`

The code should be -

```
private $filter_keys = array(
  'filter_warranty_id',
  'filter_service_centre_id'
);

foreach($this->filter_keys as $filter) {
  $$filter = 'bla';
}

var_dump($filter_warranty_id);
```

**Output**

```
string(3) "bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach($this->filter_keys as $filter) {
    $$filter = 'bla';
}
```